# Template missing error in Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Hi i am facing the following error while trying to create a user using Rails 3.

Error:

```
Template is missing

Missing template admins/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "C:/Site/swargadwar_admin/app/views"
```

Please check my below code and try to help me to resolve this error.

## views/homes/index.html

```
<div class="container">
    <div style="text-align:center;"><img src="/assets/admin.png" style="width:100px; height:120px; " /></div>
    <div class="text-div" style="text-align:center;">Swargadwar, Puri Municipality,govt of odisha</div>
            <section>               
                <div id="container_demo" >
                    <!-- hidden anchor to stop jump http://www.css3create.com/Astuce-Empecher-le-scroll-avec-l-utilisation-de-target#wrap4  -->
                    <a class="hiddenanchor" id="toregister"></a>
                    <a class="hiddenanchor" id="tologin"></a>
                    <div id="wrapper">
                        <div id="login" class="animate form">
                            <form  action="mysuperscript.php" autocomplete="on"> 
                                <h1>Log in</h1> 
                                <p> 
                                    <label for="username" class="uname" data-icon="u" > Your email or username </label>
                                    <input id="username" name="username" required type="text" placeholder="myusername or mymail@mail.com"/>
                                </p>
                                <p> 
                                    <label for="password" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p"> Your password </label>
                                    <input id="password" name="password" required type="password" placeholder="eg. X8df!90EO" /> 
                                </p>
                                <p class="keeplogin"> 
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="loginkeeping" id="loginkeeping" value="loginkeeping" /> 
                                    <label for="loginkeeping">Keep me logged in</label>
                                </p>
                                <p class="login button"> 
                                    <input type="submit" value="Login" /> 
                                </p>
                                <p class="change_link">
                                    Not a member yet ?
                                    <a href="#toregister" class="to_register">Join us</a>
                                </p>
                            </form>
                        </div>

                        <div id="register" class="animate form">
                            <%= form_for :admins,:url => {:action => 'create_registration',:controller => "admins" } do |f| %>
                                <h1> Sign up </h1> 
                                <p> 
                                    <label for="usernamesignup" class="uname" data-icon="u">Your username</label>
                                    <%= f.text_field :user_name,placeholder:"mysuperusername690",:id => "usernamesignup" %>
                                </p>
                                <p> 
                                    <label for="emailsignup" class="youmail" data-icon="e" > Your email</label>
                                     <%= f.email_field :email,placeholder:"mysupermail@mail.com",:id => "emailsignup" %>
                                </p>
                                <p> 
                                    <label for="passwordsignup" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p">Your password </label>
                                    <%= f.password_field :password,placeholder:"eg. X8df!90EO",:id => "passwordsignup" %>
                                </p>
                                <p> 
                                    <label for="passwordsignup_confirm" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p">Please confirm your password </label>
                                    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation,placeholder:"eg. X8df!90EO",:id => "passwordsignup" %>
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                     <label for="usernamesignup" class="uname" data-icon="u">Add Image</label>
                                     <%= f.file_field :picture %>
                                </p>
                                <p class="signin button">
                                <%= f.submit "Sign Up"%> 
                                </p>
                                <p class="change_link">  
                                    Already a member ?
                                    <a href="#tologin" class="to_register"> Go and log in </a>
                                </p>
                                <% end %>
                        </div>
                        <div class="error-div">
                                    <% if @admin.errors.any? %>
                                      <div id="error_explanation">
                                      <h2><%= pluralize(@admin.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

                                      <ul>
                                      <% @admin.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                                     <li><%= msg %></li>
                                     <% end %>
                                     </ul>
                                    </div>
                                  <% end %>
                               </div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </section>
        </div>
```

## controller/admins_controller.rb

```
class AdminsController < ApplicationController
    def create_registration
        @admin=Admin.new(params[:admin])
        if @admin.save
            flash[:notice]="User has created successfully"
            flash[:color]="valid"
            redirect_to :action => "index" , :controller => "homes"
        else
            flash[:alert]="User could not created"
            flash[:color]="invalid"
            render 'index', :controller => "homes"
        end
    end
end
```

## routes.rb

```
SwargadwarAdmin::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => "homes#index"
  get "homes/index" => "homes#index"
  post "admins/create_registration" => "admins#create_registration"
end
```

## controller/homes_controller.rb

```
class HomesController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @admin=Admin.new
    end
end
```

Actually i was trying by insert wrong data for checking validation and got this error at this line `"render 'index',:controller => 'homes'"`.Please help me.

Comment: Can you try `render 'homes/index'` ?

Comment: @Arup I will try that but suppose if part will excute then it should remain same or not.

Comment: no.. `redirect_to` and `render` is not same. Read [this](http://brettu.com/rails-daily-ruby-tip-28-whats-the-difference-between-redirect_to-and-render-in-rails/)